# jquery get JSON issues

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, validation

I'm new to server validation and I've looked all over the web and can't find a thing.  I'm trying to validate a form with php by posting it to itself and returning a 1 or a 0 in an array depending on whether the form is valid or not.  That works fine but the issue I'm having is I want to make the log in screen fade out if the result is 1.  I can't get that to work.

Here's my code:

The PHP

```
if ($valid == 1) {

$isvalid = array('valid' => $valid);


echo json_encode(array_values($isvalid));

};
```

The javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#login_button').click(function(){ 

$.getJSON("/index.php",function(result){
console.log(result);


});
});

});
</script>
```

nothing outputs into the console, I've also tried alert and nothing happens.  The JSON seems to be working in the top left corner I get a [1] which should be what I need.

Here is my whole code maybe it's a matter of placing the script?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">
</script>

\\wait to load the script until the document is ready

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//on submission

$('#login_button').click(function(){ 

//check if login was valid

$.getJSON("localhost/index.php",function(result){
console.log(result) .error(function() {console.log('error');});


});
});

});
</script>

<?PHP

$valid = 0;


//Declare the database connection

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root");
if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Has the form been submitted?

if(isset($_POST['Username'])){








//Check if Username and PW correct
 mysql_select_db ("Users",$con);

  $sqlCheckUser = mysql_query ( "select Username from userinfo where UserName = '$_POST[Username]' && Password = MD5('$_POST[Password]')");


  //Parse Results


  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlCheckUser); 

//is the login valid

  if (isset($row) && !empty ($row))  {


 $valid = 1;

   }

   else {
       $badpw = "Invalid Username or Password";
   }

}


//handle if form has not been submitted



else {
echo "<center>Please Enter Username and Password</center><br />";
};



if ($valid == 1) {

$isvalid = array('valid' => $valid);


echo json_encode(array_values($isvalid));

};




?>

</head>
```

I validated my JSON, it looks good does anyone know what's going on?  I really need this to work.

EDIT

Ok so appending this onto my code does give me the error.

the script now looks like the following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#login_button').click(function(){ 

$.getJSON("index.php",$('#Login').serialize(),function(result){

alert(result);

})




.error(function(error) { alert(error); console.log(error); })


})

});
</script>
```

The alert text is [object Object]

The console output is this:

```
object ready state: 0
getResponseHeader: Function
getAllRequestHeaders: Function
SetRequestHeader: Function
overrideimetype: function
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/roQ6J.jpg
(I took a screenshot because it wouldn't stay in the console long enough for me to read it)

Comment: You are calling `console.log(json)`, but the argument of your callback is `result`.

Comment: Sorry I would edit this post but it's not letting me.

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#login_button').click(function(){ 

$.getJSON("/index.php",function(result){
    console.log(result);
 
 
});
});

});
</script>

still not returning results

Comment: Does the network tab show you anything useful?  Or if chrome isn't available, this program is more featureful for the same purpose http://www.charlesproxy.com/   P.S, I'll make your edit for you.

Comment: Is your index.php file located on the document root? If not, then try changing "/index.php" into "index.php".

Comment: yes it is on the root.  I'm running XAMP  to test this so the site containing both the JavaScript and php and html are all on localhost/index.php

Comment: Your index.php might not be returning a correctly formatted json.  Try appending `.error(function() {console.log('error');})` after the $.getJSON function, ie:  `$.getJSON("/index.php",function(result){
 console.log(result);
})
.error(function() {console.log('error');});` and see what you get on the console.

Comment: Same result.  One thing I noticed looking at the network is that jquery-1.9.1.min.js is stuck in pending, it never makes a request.  Why would that be?

Comment: The source of your jquery file might be unavailable/unreachable. Have you tried changing the jquery source to `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js`?

Comment: I can't imagine that being the case since it's on the root folder I just downloaded it because at times my network connection is not the best.  a simple alert function does appear to make a call to the jquery parser just not the get json

Comment: Try relocating your PHP code from `<head></head>` to `<body></body>`?

Comment: still returned no results to the console and no traffic to the network.  could it be that the JavaScript is included in the php file I'm trying to get the json from?

Comment: Try this and let me know if this is close to what you're trying to achieve http://codepad.org/qKEt9sHO

Comment: Well that at least gives me something, but now I'm getting an unexpected token when I attempt to validate the form.  Why does this output information and get.json does not?

Answer (score 0):

your response data is on `result` variable as in your callback function, so change:

```
console.log(json);
```

to

```
console.log(result);
```